# Proper use of extract function?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to select names of employees who were born in 1985.

I am doing this but it is giving me an error.

```
SQL> select fname, lname, count(E#) as "total"
  2  extract(year from date, dob) as "year"
  3  from employee
  4  where "year"=1985;
extract(year from date, dob) as "year"
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 


SQL> select fname, lname, count(E#) as "total"
  2  from employee
  3  where extract(year from date, dob) =1985
  4  group by fname, lname;
where extract(year from date, dob) =1985
                        *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: You can only extract from one column: `extract(year from dob)`. For details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: You also miss a comma after the `as "total"` in the 1st query - that's why it complaints about a missing `FROM`.

Comment: @DBAstudent, Also miss in 1st query in where caluse .. like year ='1985' ;

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan OP has not mentioned the data type of year column. Did he? Perhaps he is storing year as NUMBER. So, why do you think he should put the single-quotation marks at all? Though it is a bad design.

Comment: I have fname, lname, dob as attributes and i need to get all names with 1985 dob

Comment: fname, lname varchar and dob as dat @ lalit

Comment: Ok, you can see the updated answer.

Comment: lol..how do i mark as answered,,can't find the thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a **missing comma** after the alias "Total" in your first query.
2. **Extract** will take **single column** as input, while you are giving two columns.

You could do it like:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(deptno)          AS "total",
  2    extract(YEAR FROM hiredate) AS "year"
  3  FROM emp
  4  GROUP BY extract(YEAR FROM hiredate);

     total       year
---------- ----------
         2       1982
         1       1983
         1       1980
        10       1981

SQL>
```

**UPDATE**

Using the WHERE clause:

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(deptno)          AS "total",
  2    extract(YEAR FROM hiredate) AS "year"
  3  FROM emp
  4  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hiredate) = 1981
  5  GROUP BY extract(YEAR FROM hiredate);

     total       year
---------- ----------
        10       1981

SQL>
```

Comment: why not use "Where" Clause. Because In Oracle The WHERE clause is used to filter the results from a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan It was just an example to demonstrate the simple use of EXTRACT. Has nothing functional relevance.